# Median of 8 values from a text file

Tags: python, parsing, text, median

I have a text file with like 36000 values. One value in each row. 
I need to calculate the median of 8 values then move to the next 8 values and so on. This is the code i've written so far.

```
num_lines = open('median_raw.txt').read().count('\n')
print(num_lines)
median_values =0
count2 = count1

while count2<=num_lines:
    file_name = open("median_raw.txt", 'r+')
    f= open('median_parsed' + '.txt', 'w+')
    for line_no1, line1 in enumerate (file_name):
        median_values=(statistics.median([line1, int(next(line1))]))
        f.writelines([median_values])
        count2= count2+8

file_name.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: please explain your problem with example, what is count1 ?

Comment: Okay, and what is your question? Did the code do something different from what you expect? Is there a part of the problem you don't think you know how to do? If so, which?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something more idiomatic. It is using `islice` from itertools which reads in the lines 8 at a time, holding only 8 in memory at one time. So for a larger file you wont see issues with memory.

```
from itertools import islice
from statistics import median

with open('median_raw.txt') as f, open('median_parsed.txt', 'w+') as fout:

    while True:

        val = [int(s) for s in islice(f, 8)]

        if not val:
            break

        avg = median(val)

        print(f'the median of {val} is {avg}')
        fout.write(f'{avg}\n')
```

This should work fine even if the number of lines in the input aren't divisble by 8. We stop iterating when `islice` returns at empty list.

Comment: A slightly more efficient solution is to simply write `avg = median(map(int, islice(f, 8)))` and catch `statistics.StatisticsError` to break the loop.

Comment: @GZ0 thanks. I had considered the map option. I wanted to keep hold of the list values, as well as the median. It's certainly worth considering if the OP doesn't need to keep hold of the lists.

Comment: @Paul Even if the list needs to be kept, using `try ... except ...` surrounding the entire loop is slightly more efficient than an `if` statement within the loop. The latter might be intuitive though.

Comment: @GZ0 please feel free to add your own answer, if you think it can be improved.

Comment: I don't think such minor variation for efficiency is worth another answer. Moreover, your answer may be easier to understand anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
file_name = open("median_raw.txt", 'r+')
f = open('median_parsed.txt', 'w+')

for bin in range(len(open('median_raw.txt').read().count('\n'))/8):
    median_values=(statistics.median(file_name[8*bin:8 + 8*bin]))
    f.writelines([median_values])
f.close()
```

Line 1 will create a range for you to iterate through your file in sets of 8.
Each new loop will then collect the mean of 0 to 8 modulated by the current 'bin'.

This will only work if your starting file newline length is divisible by 8